# jQuery default for ajax statusCode

Tags: jquery, default, http-status-codes

As far as I understand, one possibility to handle error results with ajax is the following one:

```
$.ajax({
    url: someUrl,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {},
    error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
            alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
            alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
            alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
            alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
            alert('Time out error.');
        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
            alert('Ajax request aborted.');
        } else {
            alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    }
});
```

Or use `statusCode` in order to make it more readable:

```
$.ajax({
    url: someUrl,
    type: 'POST',
    statusCode: {
        200: function(data) {
                   :
                   :
             },
        401: function() {
                   :
                   :
             },
              :
              :
```

**My question is:**
Is it possible to use `statusCode` and have a default fall-through for it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Not in the statusCode parameter. But that's because a better (and leaner) way if you want to catch everything:

```
complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    switch (jqXHR.status) {
        case 200:
            alert("200 received! yay!");
            break;
        case 404:
            alert("404 received! boo!");
            break;
        default:
            alert("I don't know what I just got but it ain't good!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! really clean and simple. Just for those who are going to use it I would add that in order to get the json from the request you need to use `data = jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);`